# CompletableFuture vs Spring Transactions

Tags: java, spring, multithreading, hibernate, transactions

**Idea**

I have a processing method which takes in a list of items and processes them asynchronously using external web service. The process steps also persist data while processing. At the end of whole process, I want to persist the whole process along with each processed results as well.

**Problem**

I convert each item in the list into `CompletableFuture` and run a processing task on them, and put them back into an array of futures. Now using its `.ofAll` method (in sequence method) to complete future when all the submitted tasks are completed and return another `CompletableFuture` which holds the result.

When I want to get that result, I call `.whenComplete(..)`, and would want to set the returned result into my entity as data, and then persist to the database, however the repository save call just does nothing and continues threads just continue running, it's not going past the repository save call.

```
 @Transactional
 public void process(List<Item> items) {
   List<Item> savedItems = itemRepository.save(items);

   final Process process = createNewProcess();

   final List<CompletableFuture<ProcessData>> futures = savedItems.stream()
     .map(item -> CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> doProcess(item, process), executor))
     .collect(Collectors.toList());

   sequence(futures).whenComplete((data, throwable) -> {
     process.setData(data);
     processRepository.save(process); // <-- transaction lost?
     log.debug("Process DONE"); // <-- never reached
   });
  }
```

Sequence method

```
 private static <T> CompletableFuture<List<T>> sequence(List<CompletableFuture<T>> futures) {
    CompletableFuture<Void> allDoneFuture =
      CompletableFuture.allOf(futures.toArray(new CompletableFuture[futures.size()]));
    return allDoneFuture.thenApply(v ->
      futures.stream().map(CompletableFuture::join).collect(Collectors.toList())
    );
  }
```

What is happening? Why is the persist call not passing. Is the thread that started the transaction not able to commit the transaction or where does it get lost? All the processed data returns fine and is all good. I've tried different transaction strategies, but how is it possible to control which thread is gonna finish the transaction, if it's the case?

Any advice?

Comment: what about `sequence` method, can you show it?

Comment: It's jus glue code to perform allOf on the list of futures.

Comment: I'm not 100% on this but it looks like the `Transactional` starts the transaction on method start and commits on method finish, `Transactional` does not wait for your callbacks to be fired. You could test that with simple thread.

Comment: Well I assume so too. If I would do `List<ProcessData> data = sequence(futures).join()` and then repository.save(data), the method blocks and commits fine, I cannot block, but still would need a way to perform it in transaction from start to finish.

Comment: @stjepano you are right Transactional start transaction at the begining of the execution and commit (or rollback if runtime error) at the end of the method.

Comment: @Vaelyr I would in this case remove the `@Transactional` and use `PlatformTransactionManager` and then do manual commits/rollbacks. But please note that I am not in the `Spring` development for quite some time now

Comment: @Vaelyr  how did you achieve this, can you please help?

Answer (score 8):

The reason of your problem is, as said above, that the transaction ends 
when the return of method process(..) is reached.

What you can do, is create the transaction manually, that gives you full
control over when it starts and ends.

Remove @Transactional

Autowire the TransactionManager then in process(..) :

```
    TransactionDefinition txDef = new DefaultTransactionDefinition();
    TransactionStatus txStatus = transactionManager.getTransaction(txDef);
    try {
    //do your stuff here like
        doWhateverAsync().then(transactionManager.commit(txStatus);)
    } catch (Exception e) {
        transactionManager.rollback(txStatus);
        throw e;
    }
```

Comment: Important to note that doWhateverAsync must operate in the same transactional context created. Care should be taken when doing operations in other threads since the same context may not be available.

Comment: @vishr just adding on that any work happening in CompletableFuture will it have the transaction even if we are manually closing the the transaction after the completion of the future, because as per my understanding completablefuture would be running on a new thread(or executable thread pool) not the the thread on which our request was being served. And the new thread might not have same context.

Comment: How do you autowire the transaction?

Comment: It might not be the only reason, it seems that the transaction is not propagated to threads created by the @Transactional-annotated method : https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/25439

Answer (score 4):

In case of Spring Boot Application , you need following configurations.

The main application method should be annotated with @EnableAsync.

@Async annotation should be on the top of method having @Transactional annotation. This is necessary to indicate processing will be taking place in child thread.

Comment: Just adding the @Async annotation failed to persist anything in my case. And I don't see any inserts in the debug sesstion