# Spring boot manage multiple transactions

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa, spring-transactions

I have spring boot app with multiple databases and in services I want to talk to those databases and combine info from 2 of them in the same method.

```
@Service
@Transactional("transactionManager1")
public class Service1 {
```

```
@Service
@Transactional("transactionManager2")
public class Service2 {
```

I have some methods in Service1 that also call methods from Service2 to get some data from other database.

It worked fine until I added threading. In Service1 I added `CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(....)` that calls method from Service1 that in turn eventually calls Service2 methods. And at some point it just throws me TransactionException.

To fix this I thought I would manually create transaction before `CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(....)` and commit it afterwards. When I was searching how to do that I got idea from [CompletableFuture vs Spring Transactions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35628764/completablefuture-vs-spring-transactions) and started writing the following code (I use PlatformTransactionManager instead):

```
@TimeLimiter(name = "method1")
public CompletableFuture<Void> method1Async(long arg1) {
    TransactionDefinition txDef = new DefaultTransactionDefinition();
    TransactionStatus txStatus = platformTransactionManager.getTransaction(txDef);
    CompletableFuture<Void> x = null;
    try {
      x = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {
          Void y = this.method1(arg1);
          platformTransactionManager.commit(txStatus);
          return y;
        })
        .toCompletableFuture();
    } catch (Exception e){
      platformTransactionManager.rollback(txStatus);
    }
    return x;
}
```

But after still getting exception about transaction I realized that since I use  multiple databases I probably need multiple transaction managers. But when I was trying to learn those transaction managers I didn't notice any way to tell for which database I want it.

How Do I create another transaction for transactionManager2?

Comment: If you have multiple database you don't need multiple transaction managers but 2PC https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/io.html#io.jta

Comment: What does PC mean in this context?

Comment: Two phase commit https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two-phase_commit_protocol