# org.hibernate.PersistentObjectException: detached entity passed to persist inside CompletableFuture.runAsync()

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, entitymanager, completable-future

Hey can anyone help me in this, Getting a weird error.

I have two Entities:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="dbdetails")
public class DBdetails {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    Long id;
    String domain;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="dbdetails")
    List<Action> actions=new ArrayList<>();
public DBdetails(String domain) {
        this.dommain = domain;
    }
}
```

and

```
@Entity
public class Action
{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    Long id;

    String action;

    String medium;
 @JsonIgnore
    @ManyToOne(cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST,CascadeType.MERGE},
            optional = true)
    @JoinColumn(name="dbdetails_id", nullable=true
    )
    DBdetails dbdetails;

public Action(String action, String medium, DBdetails dbdetails) {
        this.action = action;
        this.medium = medium;
        this.dbdetails = dbdetails;
       
    }

}
```

And have usual JpaRepositories for both Entities:

```
@Repository
public interface ActionRepository extends JpaRepository<Action,Long> {}

@Repository
public interface MyRepository extends JpaRepository<DBdetails,Long> {

}

@Autowired
ActionRepository actionRepository;

@Autowired
MyRepository repo;
```

Now while i run this method, it works fine:

```
public void checkCascade1()
    {
            DBdetails db=repo.findById(29l).get();
            Action action1=new Action("test1","test",db);
            actionRepository.save(action1);//},threadPoolExecutor).whenComplete((s,err)->{logger.info(err.getMessage());err.printStackTrace();});
    }
```

but when i run this method:

```
public void checkCascade()
    {
        CompletableFuture.runAsync(()->{
            checkCascade1();
           },threadPoolExecutor).whenComplete((s,err)->{logger.info(err.getMessage());err.printStackTrace();});

    }
```

it gives following error:

```
java.util.concurrent.CompletionException: org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: detached entity passed to persist: com.namekart.amp2.Entity.DBdetails; nested exception is org.hibernate.PersistentObjectException: detached entity passed to persist: com.namekart.amp2.Entity.DBdetails
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.encodeThrowable(CompletableFuture.java:315)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.completeThrowable(CompletableFuture.java:320)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncRun.run(CompletableFuture.java:1807)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncRun.exec(CompletableFuture.java:1796)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:373)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.topLevelExec(ForkJoinPool.java:1182)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.scan(ForkJoinPool.java:1655)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1622)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:165)
Caused by: org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: detached entity passed to persist: com.namekart.amp2.Entity.DBdetails; nested exception is org.hibernate.PersistentObjectException: detached entity passed to persist: com.namekart.amp2.Entity.DBdetails
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateJpaDialect.java:297)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:233)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.translateExceptionIfPossible(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:551)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.java:61)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.DataAccessUtils.translateIfNecessary(DataAccessUtils.java:242)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:152)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:174)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:97)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:215)
    at jdk.proxy3/jdk.proxy3.$Proxy193.save(Unknown Source)
    at com.namekart.amp2.Controller.NamesiloController.checkCascade1(NamesiloController.java:232)
    at com.namekart.amp2.Controller.NamesiloController.lambda$checkCascade$0(NamesiloController.java:215)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncRun.run(CompletableFuture.java:1804)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.PersistentObjectException: detached entity passed to persist: com.namekart.amp2.Entity.DBdetails
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:120)
    at org.hibernate.event.service.internal.EventListenerGroupImpl.fireEventOnEachListener(EventListenerGroupImpl.java:118)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.firePersist(SessionImpl.java:780)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:748)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.CascadingActions$7.cascade(CascadingActions.java:298)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeToOne(Cascade.java:510)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeAssociation(Cascade.java:434)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeProperty(Cascade.java:220)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascade(Cascade.java:153)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.cascadeBeforeSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:427)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSaveOrReplicate(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:264)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:193)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:123)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:185)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:128)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:55)
    at org.hibernate.event.service.internal.EventListenerGroupImpl.fireEventOnEachListener(EventListenerGroupImpl.java:107)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.firePersist(SessionImpl.java:756)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:742)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$SharedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:311)
    at jdk.proxy3/jdk.proxy3.$Proxy149.persist(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.save(SimpleJpaRepository.java:666)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker$RepositoryFragmentMethodInvoker.lambda$new$0(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:289)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker.doInvoke(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:137)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker.invoke(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:121)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition$RepositoryFragments.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:530)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:286)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$ImplementationMethodExecutionInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:640)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:164)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:139)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:81)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:123)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:388)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:119)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:137)
    ... 16 more
```

Also it doesn't give error while executing:

```
public void checkCascade()
    {
        CompletableFuture.runAsync(()->{
            DBdetails db=new DBdetails("test");
            Action action1=new Action("test1","test",db);
            actionRepository.save(action1);
           },threadPoolExecutor).whenComplete((s,err)->{logger.info(err.getMessage());err.printStackTrace();});

    }
```

But gets same error in:

```
public void checkCascade()
    {
        CompletableFuture.runAsync(()->{
            DBdetails db=new DBdetails("test");
            repo.save(db)
            Action action1=new Action("test1","test",db);
            actionRepository.save(action1);
           },threadPoolExecutor).whenComplete((s,err)->{logger.info(err.getMessage());err.printStackTrace();});

    }
```

I am unable to understand why the DBdetails entity is getting detached from persistent context (if i am accessing a already saved DBdetails entity) before executing actionRepository.save() as everything is happening in same thread although Asynchronously.

PS: I am using a ForkJoinPool as threadPoolExecutor:

```
    public ForkJoinPool threadPoolExecutor() {
        ForkJoinPool threadPoolExecutor = (ForkJoinPool) Executors.newWorkStealingPool(15);
        return threadPoolExecutor;
    }
```

Comment: Most likely as the transaction is closed. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35628764/completablefuture-vs-spring-transactions